# quadratic over Z7 no solutions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics

I was given the question
Solve this formula for X1 and X2 over Z7 (mod7)

$$
3x^2+x+1 = 0
$$

So I went on and converted it to the quadratic formula over Z7 like and solved it like so:
$$
\frac{6\pm \sqrt{1+3*3*1}}{6} = 
\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4*3*1}}{6} =
\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{3}}{6} =
$$

And... now what?
Can this even be solved? is it correct to say that there is no solution as $$\sqrt{3}$$ does not exist in Z7?
Am I missing something?

Comment: This is correct, however you need to check if $\sqrt{3}$ exists in $\mathbb{F}_7$. For example $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{C}$, but $\sqrt{3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. So what about $\mathbb{F}_7$? Well, the easiest thing to do is to check if any of the seven elements of $\mathbb{F}_7$ is square root of $3$, that is if $a^2=3$ for some $a\in\mathbb{F}_7$. You can do it now by checking all seven elements, but there are also faster ways, and it can be done for larger fields.

Answer (score 1):

MOD 7

$$ 5(3x^2 + x + 1) \equiv x^2 +5x+5 \equiv (x-1)^2 - 3 \pmod 7  $$
and $(3|7) = -1;$ $3$ is not a square mod 7. The squares are $0,1,2,4 \pmod 7$

MOD 5

$$ 2(3x^2 + x + 1) \equiv x^2 +2x+2 \equiv (x+1)^2 + 1 \equiv (x+1)^2 - 4 \pmod 5  $$
and $4$ has square roots $2,-2 \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5,$ these are $x+1$ so $x \equiv 1,2 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is no solution, but not for the reason you're giving here. The quadratic equation only holds if we're working in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ or something similar (like a subring of one of those). In the case of $\mathbb Z / 7\mathbb Z$, there are only seven elements to consider, so you can simply try plugging each of them into $3x^2 + x + 1$ and verify that none of them is a zero.

Comment: This is not exactly true. The quadratic formula holds as long as the steps you need for its deduction hold, that is, that $2a$ has an inverse in the field you are. In this case $2a = 6$, which does inverts$. So, you can apply it theoretically, and the issue would indeed be if the root makes sense.

Comment: That's a good point. It would be better to say something along the lines of "what you've written is not correct because it's clear from what you've written that you're thinking of $\mathbb R$"

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the answer, however, I did manage to solve the same equation over Z5, x=1,2, is that incorrect then?